# Make a COUNT list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good morning,

I have a dynamic list of all used words in a certain file.

When I type something **D2**, it scrapes new data.

This new data then gets =unique in **F75:AH100**.

This data then gets listed in **Sheet B**.

Next step would be to put a count of all the unique data in **Sheet B**. This so we can see the importance of a certain string with multiple scraped data points.

Can this be done with a formula or should I use a script?

Example file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14ewg-2oJHe1GWaeY_zoRvaxKSWYDnPkiyOlTE_C504w/edit#gid=0

If there is anything unclear, please let me know and I will update this topic as soon as possible!

I know the formula used for Sheet B is dynamic and will change when new data is entered in A. I already have a script for that.

Thinking logically it should be something in the line of

**"If cell is counted, then take that value as minimum, and then go on with normal count"**

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(B3:B; B3:B; ROW(B3:B); "<="&ROW(B3:B)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @player0 . Unfortunately this didnt work. It should receive the outcome in B, and then go from there. I added a screenshot so it might help: 

[link](https://i.imgur.com/Mk9RkCv.png)